# SocketIO on port 80 together with Express

Tags: node.js, express, websocket, socket.io

I have ExspressJS app run with Socket.io, due to firewall issues with higher port for SIO i want to switch that both will work on port 80.

Found this [small article](http://braindrivendevelopment.com/2013/09/24/node-js-how-to-run-express-and-socket-io-on-the-same-port/) and on my dev machine it's look working good.

My question is, is it really goo to do that? is it a good practice? if not why?

Please advise.

Answer (score 4):

It makes absolute sense to run socket.io and your web server on the same port.

The webSocket protocol (which socket.io is based on) is specifically designed for this to be the primary way that socket.io is used for a bunch of reasons including same-origin permissions and client and server firewall routing of port 80.

In case you didn't realize it, every socket.io connection starts with an HTTP request to a specific route and then once the initial handshake between client and server has been confirmed, then the protocol is "upgraded" from HTTP to webSocket.  Because all socket.io connections connect in on a very specific route, all other HTTP connections can easily be separated out and be treated by your web server as regular web requests.